# Most gas efficient way to convert uint256 into a handful of uint8s

Tags: solidity, evm, assembly

I am working on a card game. I have a problem where I am choosing to store a representation of 32 uint8s inside one uint256 word in order to save on gas. I store the uint256 word and then want to deserialize a handful (no less than 4, no more than 5) uint8s from the uint256 word and then pass the specific uint8s based on the method I want to validate that I've "won" the game. So far this has been my approach but I have a feeling someone knows the assembly well enough to eek out just a bit more performance.

```
    function _verify(Game storage game, uint256 card, WinWay way) internal view returns (bool) {
        bytes memory bytesifiedCard = abi.encode(card);
        uint8[32] memory cardInNumbers = abi.decode(bytesifiedCard, (uint8[32]));
        
        // pass specific 4 or 5 indices according to which WinWay you want to verify from
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want up to 5 `uint8`, I think declaring them as separate `uint8` variables are a lot cleaner:

```
    /**
     * @dec encode 5 parameters into uint
     * @return card encoded card id
     */
    function encode(uint8 param1, uint8 param2, uint8 param3, uint8 param4, uint8 param5)
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint256 card)
    {
        unchecked {
            card = (uint256(param1) << 32) + (uint256(param1) << 24) + (uint256(param1) << 16) + (uint256(param1) << 8) + uint256(param1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev   Decode uint256 to 5 parameters
     */
    function decode(uint256 card)
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint8 param1, uint8 param2, uint8 param3, uint8 param4, uint8 param5)
    {
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly {
            param1 := shr(32, card)
            param2 := shr(24, card)
            param3 := shr(16, card)
            param4 := shr(8, card)
            param5 := card
        }
    }
```

So you core logic can be:

```
function _verify(Game storage game, uint256 card, WinWay way) internal view returns (bool) {
        (uint8 param1, uint8 param2, uint8 param3, uint8 param4, uint8 param5) 
        = card.decode();

        // pass specific 4 or 5 indices according to which WinWay you want to verify from
        if (way == WinWay.A) {
             your_other_function_A(param1, param2, param3);
        } else if (way == WinWay.B) {
             your_other_function_B(param2, param3, param3, param4, param5);
        }
```

Comment: I should probably add more context, they are all at varying points of the card. So at some points I would normally be passing 

[cardInNumbers[2], cardInNumbers[7], cardInNumbers[16], cardInNumbers[21]]
and others maybe
[cardInNumbers[10], cardInNumbers[11], cardInNumbers[12], cardInNumbers[13]]

so its not quite a simple decode and encode problem like so. Need to be able to jump around. Not sure this would handle that.

Comment: would your function have a fix set of indices to pass?
like would the first function always takes index 2,7,16,21
and a second function always takes 10, 11, 12, 13? 

I feel like the best way would be passing in `card` into each functions and let them parse the indices they want, instead of storing everything in an array and then pass fix set of indices to a function

Comment: it's always either 4 or 5 and then just reads from storage to see if the variables have been found. But WinWay determines which part of the card to read from and verify.

Comment: how about the indexes? how do you determine if it's 10, 11, 12, 13 or 11, 12, 13, 14?

Comment: Based on the winway, like if I need to validate that you won by going across, I need to get all the coordinates for across and then validate that the value in uint8 has been found there.

Comment: either way, I didn't know that just shifting right would auto decode them into the uint8...that's actually pretty helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I think you can play around with it and refactor a bit to let the two function that takes 4 and 5 inputs, determine which ones to decode and parse it dynamically from `card`. (instead of having everything in an length 32 array)